# PostgreSQL thinks there are no indices, when there are

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

We have one large PostgreSQL in our production. Recently, we saw that our queries have become extremely slow. So we inspected it and it all came down to checking the indices for a sample table. So we ran the following query to check if there were any indices:

```
select * from pg_indexes where tablename = 'DriverHourlyOnlineHoursNew'
```

We get no results for this query, which means there are no indices on our sample table. This is a bit weird, because we were almost sure that we had a btree index on two columns in this table.

So we tried adding that index to the table. We ran the following query:

```
create index "DriverHourlyOnlineHoursNew_driverId_date" on "DriverHourlyOnlineHoursNew" using btree("driverId",date);
```

and surprisingly we get the following error:

```
ERROR:  relation "DriverHourlyOnlineHoursNew_driverId_date" already exists
```

So it turns out the index actually exists, but PostgreSQL thinks that it does not!

I was wondering if anybody has any ideas what this problem is and how it can be resolved?

Thanks

**--Update:** The first query that is ran on the pg_indexes view responds randomly! Meaning that sometimes it returns an empty result set, and sometimes it returns correct results. 
One more thing I should add that proves this is not a naming problem is that running the first query returns no results, while PostgreSQL creates a default index on primary key columns and therefore returning no results means that there is something wrong with the pg_indexes view.

Comment: have you analyzed the table after index creation? it shows true on indisvalid on pg_index view? please show output of explain analyze

Comment: `select * from pg_indexes where indexname = 'DriverHourlyOnlineHoursNew_driverId_date'` relation exists - not nesesserily index on the table `DriverHourlyOnlineHoursNew`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you just tried to do something like this :

```
DROP INDEX DriverHourlyOnlineHoursNew_driverId_date;
```

Then create it again :

```
CREATE INDEX on DriverHourlyOnlineHoursNew (driverId, date);
```

You should have a pg_* table corruption.
Did you VACUUM your database regularly ?

Otherwise what you can do is simply :

```
SELECT * INTO TEMP tmp_DriverHourlyOnlineHoursNew FROM DriverHourlyOnlineHoursNew;

DROP TABLE DriverHourlyOnlineHoursNew;

SELECT * INTO DriverHourlyOnlineHoursNew FROM tmp_DriverHourlyOnlineHoursNew;

CREATE INDEX on DriverHourlyOnlineHoursNew (driverId, date);
```

And you should recover a "normal table".

Do not hesitate to do regular :

```
VACUUM ANALYZE;
```

This is not blocking and clean your database.

Comment: Can you give us which version of PostgreSQL are you using ? And did you tried to do with just copy content of you table in a new, not formaly woth same name and see if your problem disappears ... then i not I'll considere to a corrupted database and make a full dump and create a new one from the backup.

Answer (score 0):

check pg_class, or first

```
select * from pg_indexes where indexname = 'DriverHourlyOnlineHoursNew_driverId_date'
```

"relation exists" - not nesesserily index on the table "riverHourlyOnlineHoursNew", eg:

```
t=# create table a();
CREATE TABLE
t=# create table a1(i int);
CREATE TABLE
t=# create index a on a1(i);
ERROR:  relation "a" already exists
```

Comment: But there are no tables named like the index name and the query to check the indices on the tables responds randomly. So however the point you are making is valid, it does not solve the problem.